# Query the primary keys of 3 tables without repeating into a single column

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables

```
TABLE A 
      A_ID (PK)
      B_ID
      X_ID
      A_NAME

TABLE B
      B_ID (PK)
      A_ID
      B_NAME

TABLE C
      C_ID (PK)
      B_ID
      C_NAME
```

The X_ID will be bonded to a Bind Variable, based on which the primary keys will be queried.

I have to query all the primary keys from three of the tables without them repeating in the query result
 The query which I used is

```
SELECT TABLEA.A_ID,TABLEB.B_ID,TABLEC.C_ID
FROM TABLEA INNER JOIN TABLE B 
ON TABLEA.A_ID= TABLEB.A_ID JOIN TABLE C
ON TABLEB.B_ID= TABLEC.B_ID
WHERE TABLEA.X_ID = :bindVariable
ORDER BY TABLEA.A_NAME
```

**UPDATE:**

Columns and values

```
A_ID          B_ID            C_ID        X_ID
101            201             301         1
101            201             302         1
101            202             303         2
102            202             304         2
```

But I want to Show the result as based on X_ID (value `1`)

```
PK_ID
101
201
301
302
```

All the unique Id's should be shown without repeating.

Comment: Please show your attempt.

Comment: Your query will only show instances where all three tables share the same key values. Is that what you want? Your question seems to be asking something different. Can you give an example of the kind of output you're looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `UNION` operator will eliminate duplicates, so all you need is:

```
SELECT A_ID
FROM [Table A]

UNION

SELECT B_ID
FROM [Table B]

UNION

SELECT C_ID
FROM [Table C]
```

UPDATE: In chat, you said the following:

> Table A is related to Table B with A_ID and Table B and Table C are
>   related by B_ID

Based on the data above, I don't think you have a clear enough relationship to do this. You could union `A` and `B` like so:

```
SELECT A_ID
FROM [Table A]
WHERE X_ID = 1

UNION

SELECT B.B_ID
FROM [Table B] B
INNER JOIN [Table A] A
  ON B.A_ID = A.A_ID
WHERE A.X_ID = 1
```

But based on the relationships you've described, there's no way to join `C` back to `A` in such a way that you only get records where `A.X_ID` is a certain value. The best you can do is to get all values in `Table C` that match a value in `B` that matches `A.X_ID` at least *once*:

```
SELECT A_ID
FROM [Table A]
WHERE X_ID = 1

UNION

SELECT B.B_ID
FROM [Table B] B
INNER JOIN [Table A] A
  ON B.A_ID = A.A_ID
WHERE A.X_ID = 1

UNION

SELECT C_ID
FROM [Table C]
WHERE B_ID IN (
  SELECT B.B_ID
  FROM [Table B] B
  INNER JOIN [Table A] A ON B.A_ID = A.A_ID
  WHERE A.X_ID = 1
)
```

It's quite possible that there's a cleaner way to do that, but I have to get back to work.

**tl;dr:** You can get close, but you'll need a definitive relationship between `C_ID` and `X_ID` to make this work.

Comment: i did distinct of the result set from the above query and it gave me a distinct result set,  but how do i filter for values that are related to X_ID is equal to some value?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. As I mentioned in my comment above, I don't think I fully understand what you're going for. Can you update your question with a bit of sample data and show us what sort of results you're looking for?

Comment: Is there a reason your expected output above doesn't include 102, or was that just a typo? If it should include 102, then my query provides that output exactly.

Comment: Then the query above should work. If there's something you're still missing, we can move this to chat so I can ask a few more questions.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25605/discussion-between-nigel-thomas-and-jeff-rosenberg)

Comment: This query will return a B_ID irrespective of the A_ID which is under the particular X_ID.

Comment: Can you suggest a way to query the B_ID's from table which has the A_ID's got from filtering the X_ID.

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally left out some `where` statements. Fixed.